# my First Admin Page is not shown up

Tags: magento2, module, admin, page, create

I try to write a own module. After 1 week of searching I hope u can help to go on.

Its a very simple admin page.

module_dir: app/code/famberg/module_afterbuysync/

... Controller/Adminhtml/Settings/Index.php:

```
<?php
namespace Famberg\AfterbuySync\Controller\Adminhtml\Settings;


use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    const MENU_ID ="Famberg_AfterbuySync::settings";
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
                        Context $context,
                        PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);  
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu(static::MENU_ID);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('AfterbuySync Settings'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
?>
```

.../etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Famberg_AfterbuySync" setup_version="1.0.5">
    </module>
</config>
```

.../etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="afterbuysync" frontName="afterbuysync">
            <module name="Famberg_AfterbuySync" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

.../registration.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Famberg_AfterbuySync', __DIR__);
```

Everytime i get the message

> Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.

After xdebuging I see that the controller class is not loaded. The module is loaded. The menu item is shown. I dont know why the controller class does not exists.

Please help.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if your module registered into magento via command `php bin/magento module:status`

For me your module name looks invalid module_afterbuysync.
Please check by correcting dir path to `app/code/Famberg/AfterbuySync` (case sensitive)

Let me know if anything more is needed.
Chears.

Comment: No, i aligned to the documentation 2.4. The dicectory is named correctly. its shown up and enabled within module:status. I changed some elements within composer.json. After that he setup:di:compile (d) the controller. 

Currently I am not able to login in admin panel. There is no error message. I only stuck at loginpage. system.log, exeption.log, debug.log are clear. I disabled the module but nothin changed. I think that this is a common problem and nothing with my module. I will open a new question about this. thx

Comment: Ok, the error was within my module. after disabling the module i can login again. I dont know how to find the errors within my module if magento dont give any hints.

Comment: Ok, u are right. I needed to rename my folder and module. My naming is for the vendor folder right but not for app/code folder. The config files loaded but the classes are not generated. After renaming I was able to debug my project and fix all errors. Thx

Comment: Cool,If it was helpful you can upvote,